# npm code E401 Incorrect or missing password

Tags: angular, npm-install

My Node version is 18.12.1, npm version 9.5.1. When I run npm install I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login
```

I tried deleting package-lock.json file, and I have no .npmrc file to delete. I also tried clearing the proxy and cache. Any ideas what else I could do?